# datatables for mysql seems wrong

Tags: datatables, coldfusion, lucee

I have the datatables for coldfusion version 10 for mysql, but there seems to be some syntactical errors i am unable to solve and also the pagination and sorting does not work properly, it tends to keep the processing icon keeps showing even in the console it show 200, it happens on search also

my CFM Code

```
<cffunction name="getDataForTable" access="remote" returnformat="json" returntype="any" output="false"> 
    <cfargument name="inParam" type="any" default="#{}#">
    <cfset var isQueryUsed = structkeyexists(inParam,'queryName') and inParam.queryName neq ''>
    <cfif isQueryUsed>
    <cfset var qryResults = queryexecute("#PreserveSingleQuotes(inParam.queryName)#",{},{datasource='xxx'})>
    </cfif>
    <cfset var tableFields = (inParam.queryName neq '') ? qryResults.getMetaData().getColumnLabels() : inParam.Columns/>
    <cfset noOfTableFields = ArrayLen(tableFields)>
    <cfset searchFields= tableFields>
    <cfset noOfSearchFields = ArrayLen(searchFields)>

    <cfset start= Int(Val(inParam.start))>
    <cfset length= Int(Val(inParam.length))>
    <cfset search= Trim(inParam['search[value]'])>
    <cfset iSortCol_0= Int(Val(inParam['order[0][column]']))>
    <cfif LCase(inParam['order[0][dir]']) EQ 'asc'>
        <cfset sSortDir_0='asc'>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset sSortDir_0='desc'>
    </cfif>
    <cfset queryWhere="">

    <cfif (search NEQ '')> 
        <cfset queryWhere ="AND (">
        <cfloop from="1"  to="#noOfSearchFields#" index="counter">
          <cfset queryWhere=queryWhere &" lower(#searchFields[counter]#) LIKE '%#Lcase(search)#%' ">
          <cfif counter LT noOfSearchFields>
            <cfset queryWhere=queryWhere&" OR">
          </cfif>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset queryWhere=queryWhere&")">
    </cfif>
    <cfif iSortCol_0 NEQ 0>
        <cfset queryOrder='ORDER BY #tableFields[iSortCol_0 + 1]# #sSortDir_0#'>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset queryOrder=''>
    </cfif>
    <cfif length NEQ 0>
        <cfset queryLimit='LIMIT #length# OFFSET #start#'>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset queryLimit=''>
    </cfif>
    <cfif isQueryUsed>
        <cfquery name="queryResult" datasource="xxx">
            #PreserveSingleQuotes(queryName)# 
            #PreserveSingleQuotes(queryWhere)# 
            #queryOrder# 
            #queryLimit#
        </cfquery>
        <cfquery name="querycount" datasource="xxx">
            #PreserveSingleQuotes(queryName)# 
            #PreserveSingleQuotes(queryWhere)# 
            #queryOrder# 
            #queryLimit#
        </cfquery>
    <cfelse>    
        <cfquery name="queryResult" datasource="xxx">
            select #ArrayToList(tableFields)# FROM #dataTable# #PreserveSingleQuotes(queryWhere)# #queryOrder# #queryLimit#
        </cfquery>
        <cfquery name="querycount" datasource="xxx">
            select count(*) OVER() AS total FROM #dataTable# #PreserveSingleQuotes(queryWhere)# #queryOrder# #queryLimit#
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>
    <cfsavecontent variable="datatablesjson">
            <cfloop from="1"  to="#queryResult.RecordCount#" index="counter">
            <cfoutput>
                [
                <cfloop from="1"  to="#noOfTableFields#" index="innerCounter">
                    <cfif tableFields[innerCounter] EQ "start_date">
                        "#JSStringFormat(dateformat(queryResult[tableFields[innerCounter]][counter],'yyyy/mm/dd'))#"
                    <cfelse>
                        "#JSStringFormat(queryResult[tableFields[innerCounter]][counter])#"
                    </cfif>
                    <cfif innerCounter LT noOfTableFields>
                        ,
                    </cfif>
                </cfloop>
                ]
                <cfif counter LT queryResult.RecordCount>
                    ,
                </cfif>        
            </cfoutput>
            </cfloop>
    </cfsavecontent>
        <cfif queryResult.RecordCount is 0>
            <cfset datatablesjson=' [ '>
            <cfloop from="1" to="#noOfTableFields#" index="counter">
                <cfset datatablesjson=datatablesjson>
                <cfif counter LT noOfTableFields>
                    <cfset datatablesjson=datatablesjson&' , '>
                </cfif>
            </cfloop>
            <cfset datatablesjson=datatablesjson&' ] '>
        </cfif>
    <cfsavecontent variable="sGrid">    
    <cfoutput>
    {
        "draw": #Int(Val(inParam.draw))#,
        "recordsTotal": <cfif querycount.recordcount GT 0>#querycount.recordcount#<cfelse>0</cfif>,
        "recordsFiltered": <cfif querycount.recordcount GT 0>#querycount.recordcount#<cfelse>0</cfif>,   
        "data": [#datatablesjson#]
    }
    </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn sGrid>
</cffunction>
```

my datatables code

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('.display').DataTable({
        "order" : [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        
        "stateSave" : true,
        "processing" : true,
        "serverSide" : true,
        "ajax" : "ajaxprocess.cfm"
    });
});
```

ajaxprocess.cfm as :

```
<cfset sJSON = getDataForTable(url)>
<cfcontent reset="Yes" />
<cfoutput>#trim(sJSON)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: do not know why people mark -1 for questions, did not i explained or just habitual or doing it

Comment: What is the output if you run ajaxprocess.cfm on its own